# Getting "Unable to import class CommonModule" error while importing a one library into another library

Tags: angular, monorepo, angular-library, nx-angular, nx-devkit

Nx serve throws below error when I used Icon lib inside Button lib.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9qcA.png)

**Em***-Icon's module**

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { EmeraldIconComponent } from './emerald-icon/emerald-icon.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [EmeraldIconComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  exports: [EmeraldIconComponent],
})
export class EmeraldIconModule {}
```

**Eme**-button's module**

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { EmeraldButtonComponent } from './emerald-button/emerald-button.component';
import {  EmeraldIconModule } from '@emerald-ngmaterial/emerald-icon';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule,
   EmeraldIconModule
  ],
  declarations: [EmeraldButtonComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  exports: [EmeraldButtonComponent],
})
export class EmeraldButtonModule {}
```

Builds of these two libraries run successfully.

But application serve throws error, when I used Button library which imported Icon Library.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1CPl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KbX9.png)

My app works fine below scenarios,

If I include Icon library alone in app
If I include Button library without using Icon library

**Expected Behavior**
Libraries need to be imported internally. (Library inside another library)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc9qE.png)

**Steps to Reproduce**
1.Create two libaries A & B
2. Import Library BModule inside Library AModule
3. Import Library AModule in your App Module file of Angular app(demo-app).
4. Use Library A in your Angular app components
5. do run 'nx serve demo-app'

**Nx Report**

> NX   Report complete - copy this into the issue template

```
Node : 18.14.0
   OS   : darwin arm64
   npm  : 9.3.1
   
   nx : 14.1.9
   @nrwl/angular : 14.1.9
   @nrwl/cypress : 14.1.9
   @nrwl/detox : Not Found
   @nrwl/devkit : 14.1.9
   @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 14.1.9
   @nrwl/express : Not Found
   @nrwl/jest : 14.1.9
   @nrwl/js : Not Found
   @nrwl/linter : 14.1.9
   @nrwl/nest : Not Found
   @nrwl/next : Not Found
   @nrwl/node : Not Found
   @nrwl/nx-cloud : Not Found
   @nrwl/nx-plugin : Not Found
   @nrwl/react : Not Found
   @nrwl/react-native : Not Found
   @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
   @nrwl/storybook : 14.1.9
   @nrwl/web : Not Found
   @nrwl/workspace : 14.1.9
   typescript : 4.6.4
```

**Failure Logs**

```
Error: libs/emerald-button/src/lib/emerald-button.module.ts:7:13 - error NG3004: Unable to import class CommonModule.
  The symbol is not exported from /Users/SKumar51/Documents/Emerald/Library/emerald-mono-ngmaterial/node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts (module '@angular/common').

7   imports: [CommonModule,
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  libs/emerald-button/node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts:118:1
    118 export declare class CommonModule {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    119     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<CommonModule, never>;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ... 
    121     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<CommonModule>;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    122 }
        ~
    The class is declared here.


Error: libs/emerald-button/src/lib/emerald-button.module.ts:14:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?

14 export class EmeraldButtonModule {}
```

✖ Failed to compile.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same error when trying to serve an app. It turned out there was a node_modules folder in the folder with the library. That can happen if you `npm install` inside the folder where the package.json of the library is instead of the root folder. Deleting it solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You probably import `CommonModule` at the root of your application so you shouldn't export it in your Component Module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule,
   EmeraldIconModule
  ],
  declarations: [EmeraldButtonComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  exports: [EmeraldButtonComponent], // No CommonModule
})
export class EmeraldButtonModule {}
```

Comment: I am not exporting CommonModule, only importing it. If I didnt import CommonModule in Library's component Module, while building library it throws error for all directives in template file

Comment: From what I see, you export it here: `exports: [CommonModule, EmeraldButtonComponent],`

Comment: Oh yes, I just added it to check whether this error "Unable to import class CommonModule." getting fixed or not. Getting same error even after removing it. I updated the code in question now.

Comment: What's the error log when you remove it ?

Comment: getting same failure log mentioned in the question .ERROR in libs/emerald-button/src/lib/emerald-button.module.ts:8:4 - error NG3004: Unable to import class CommonModule.
  The symbol is not exported from /Users/SKumar51/Documents/Emerald/Library/emerald-mono-ngmaterial/node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts (module '@angular/common').

Comment: @sathish please, how did you fix the problem ?